# mcrypt_create_iv alternative in PHP 7.3

Tags: php

Have just upgraded from `PHP 7.0` to `PHP 7.3` and now this function is removed.. Are there any alternatives?

```
$salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(24, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

Comment: A simple search of the manual should answer your query. If the manual does not answer your quest you need to state that and why it's missed your aim. Thanks

Comment: Also judging from your own code sample; if you're generating your own encryption salt, you're very, very, **very** probably creating encrypted data *the wrong way*. Therefore making it less secure and far more open to compromise.

Comment: ** hashing salt not encryption salt in my above comment. An encryption salt is a *key*. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation for that function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php):

> Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [random_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)